# How do I get the value of multiple inputs and add them together in react native?

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, state

I want to get the miles from each of the TextInputs and add them together. How would I go about doing this? I know I need to store the input values in a new state but I can't figure out how to do this. It works for example if I take goal and subtract one of the days i.e. goal - miles.monday; but I want to add all the days together and then subtract from goal. How do I store the values so I can use array.reduce() to get the sum?

```
import react, { useEffect } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TextInput, Button, TouchableOpacity, Keyboard } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { useState } from "react";
import { ScrollView } from "react-native";

const Goal = () => {
    const [goal, setGoal] = useState();
    const [miles, setMiles] = useState({
    
         monday: 0,
           tuesday: 0,
        //  wednesday: 0,
        // thursday: 0,
        // friday: 0,
        // saturday: 0,
        // sunday: 0,

    });

    const handleChange = (day, value) => {
        setMiles({
            [day]: value,
        });

    };

    return (
        <ScrollView>
            {/* set goal */}
            <View style={styles.goalContainer}>

                <Text style={styles.goalText}>Goal: {goal}  Miles to go: {goal - miles.monday} </Text>
                <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.goalInput}
                        type="number"
                        placeholder="enter goal"
                        keyboardType="numeric"
                        value={goal}
                        onChangeText={(value) => setGoal(value)}
                    />

                </View>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.weekDayContainer}>
                <View >
                    <Text style={styles.weekDayText}>Monday</Text>
                    <TextInput style={styles.weekDayInput}
                        type="number"
                        placeholder="enter miles"
                        keyboardType="numeric"
                        value={miles.monday}
                        onChangeText={(value) => handleChange('monday', value)}
                    />
                </View>
                <View>
                    <Text style={styles.weekDayText}>Tuesday</Text>
                    <TextInput style={styles.weekDayInput}
                        type="number"
                        placeholder="enter miles"
                        keyboardType="numeric"
                        value={miles.tuesday}
                        onChangeText={(value) => handleChange('tuesday', value)}
                    />
                </View>
            </View>
        </ScrollView>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    goalContainer: {

    },


    goalText: {
        fontSize: 30,
        marginBottom: 30,
    },

    goalInput: {
        height: 50,
        width: 200,
        textAlign: 'center',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius: 60,
        marginRight: 16,

    },

    weekDayInput: {
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        width: 100,
        height: 40,
        marginBottom: 10,
        textAlign: 'center',
    },

    weekDayContainer: {
        marginTop: 80,
        marginLeft: 50,
    },

    weekDayText: {
        fontSize: 20,
        marginBottom: 10,
    },
});
export default Goal;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `handleChange` function overwrites the entire `miles` object rather than modifying it. Change your implementation to something like this:

```
const handleChange = (day, value) => {
    setMiles({ 
        ...miles,
        [day]: value,
    });

};
```